# Unity mirror roommanager roomslot not updating correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm using NetworkRoomManager script of mirror and I'm planning to create a players lobby
[image]

When a player check/uncheck the toggle it updates the syncvar of playerName and readyToBegin of that player. Below is my code

In the NetworkRoomPlayerExt script I've added this code

```
public override void OnClientEnterRoom()
{
    NetworkRoomManager room = NetworkManager.singleton as NetworkRoomManager;

    int roomCount = room.roomSlots.Count;

    NetworkRoomPlayer lastRoomPlayer = room.roomSlots[roomCount - 1];

    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(spawnPoint.position.x, 30, spawnPoint.position.z);

    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {

        GameObject playerInfoObj = Instantiate(playerInfoItem, pos, spawnPoint.rotation);
        playerInfoObj.transform.SetParent(spawnPoint, false);

        PlayerInfo playerInfo = playerInfoObj.GetComponent<PlayerInfo>();

        playerInfo.playerNameInputField.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
        {
            playerNameInput = value;
        });

        playerInfo.readyToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) => {
            CmdUpdatePlayerInfo(0, playerNameInput, value);
        });

    }
}

[Command]
public void CmdUpdatePlayerInfo(int playerIndex, string newPlayerName, bool isReady)
{
    playerName = newPlayerName;
    lastUpdatedPlayerIndex = playerIndex;
    readyToBegin = isReady;

    NetworkRoomManager room = NetworkManager.singleton as NetworkRoomManager;

    room.roomSlots[playerIndex] = this;     
}

private void PlayerUpdatedInfo(bool oldReadyState, bool newReadyState)
{
    NetworkRoomManager room = NetworkManager.singleton as NetworkRoomManager;
    Debug.Log("isLocalPlayer: " + isLocalPlayer);
    Debug.Log("room.roomSlots[lastUpdatedPlayerIndex].playerName: " + room.roomSlots[lastUpdatedPlayerIndex].playerName);
}
```

I have a syncvar callback in is readyToBegin

```
[SyncVar(hook = nameof(PlayerUpdatedInfo))]
public bool readyToBegin;
```

The Debug log returns

```
isLocalPlayer: False
room.roomSlots[0].playerName: Player 1

isLocalPlayer: True
room.roomSlots[0].playerName: Newbie
```

Now my question is why if it's the localplayer who updated the playerName it receives the latest playername which is newbie and if its not the localplayer it receives the old playername which is Player 1.

Comment: You need to SyncVar the pseudo too. That way, every pseudo will be updated on every machine (Player 1 and Player 2). I think it is that

Comment: @AdrienG. i cant understand what do you mean about pseudo

Comment: I may have not understand what you want. Can you show me the line where you have your SyncVar for the PlayerName (and the hook function)? 
Also, check this link for using SyncVar Hook : https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/guides/synchronization/syncvar-hooks You need to update the content of the variable manually in the hook so it is updated for everyone